# scrolling issues with stroll.js and JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, stroll.js

I am trying to get a simple, styled `ul` with the scroll effects from stroll.js (https://github.com/hakimel/stroll.js) to work within the JQuery framework's basic template page for later use in a website. What I find is the below code will render the `ul` on the page with a small border (courtesy of default JQuery mobile styling). However, when the user scrolls down, rather then the effects triggering sequentially as seen in the demo (http://lab.hakim.se/scroll-effects/), all the `li`'s flip over simultaneously and disappear. Weirdly though, after clicking the emulate button and then clicking the reset button in the chrome dev tool, the page works as it should. Any ides as to why this happens and/or any solutions?

Note - I've tried using the commented out meta tags without much difference. I'm also very new to JQuery.

EDIT: Found the solution. It worked after playing with the dev tools emulator because a function was called to adjust the height. I just ran that function when the page loaded and problem solved.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Stroll JQuery test</title>
<!--  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
<!-- <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1 height=device-height" /> -->


 <!-- CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stroll.css">

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- stroll -->
<script src="js/stroll.js"></script>


<!-- JQuery Mobile last -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="content">


    <div id="content">
        <ul class="cards">
            <li>
                <h2>Some Header</h2>
                <p><i>
                    "Some awesome quote from something"
                </i></p>
                <p> 
                    A short thing of text
                </p>
            </li>

            <!-- a load more <li>'s with similar content -->

         </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
        var list = document.querySelector( 'ul' );
        var type = window.location.search.slice( 1 ) || 'fly';

        list.className = type;

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', updateHeight, false );

        updateHeight();

        function updateHeight() {
            list.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
            stroll.bind( 'ul' );
        }

    </script>

</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found I had to go a little further by adding a listener to catch when the mouse was over the list and fire the resize:

```
      window.addEventListener( 'resize', updateHeight, false );

      var list = $('ul');

      function updateHeight() {
          var h = $(list).css('height');
          $(list).css('height',h);
          stroll.bind( list );
      }

      $(list).on('mouseenter', function () {
        updateHeight();
      });
```